# Copy data between two workbooks using multiple criteria

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to copy data from the Comments column of the Report to the Comments column of the Master. I have tried Vlookup and the If And functions but they have not worked because I am using multiple criteria to identify the data that needs to be copied. I am new to coding but I believe a VBA code is the solution.

Someone posted something similar but it doesn't identify the use of multiple criteria. This was their post

```
   Sub Copydata()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Dim x As Workbook
Dim y As Workbook

Set x = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\User1\Documents\Workbook1.xlsx")
Set y = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\User1\Documents\Workbook2.xlsx")
With x.Sheets("Sheet1").UsedRange
    'Now, paste to y worksheet:
    y.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1").Resize( _
        .Rows.Count, .Columns.Count) = .Value
End With
x.Close
y.Close SaveChanges:=True
End Sub
```

Below is an extract of the 2 worksheets in different workbooks

Report

[Report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j9zOe.png)

Master

[Master](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4xebb.png)

Comment: `doesn't identify the use of multiple criteria` if you study the code, it doesn't identify _any_ criteria XD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A non-VBA solution: 
In one of the columns on the "Master" tab, concatenate the criteria you're looking up. Concatenate the criteria the same way on the "Report" tab. Then use a VLOOKUP or INDEX-MATCH looking up by the concatenated criteria.

Brief Example:

Master

```
 FNames      LNames   Concat                Comment
 Bill        Smith    =Concatenate(A1,B1)   =VLOOKUP(C1, Report!D1:D2)
 John        Jones    =Concatenate(A1,B1)   =VLOOKUP(C2, Report!D1:D2)
```

Report

```
 FNames      LNames   Concat                Comment
 Bill        Smith    =Concatenate(A1,B1)   Bill report submitted
 John        Jones    =Concatenate(A1,B1)   John report not submitted
```

Comment: It worked! Thanks! I joined the criteria so that it will be easier to identify and as a result the VLookup worked!